# Pandas - count how many total items were in each month (with a cumulative sum?)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of items

```
id date [other_cols]
1 2015-01-01 ...
2 2015-05-13 ...
3 2015-08-05 ...
```

(where dates are "purchase dates" for each item)
and I would like to count how many items in total were in the inventory in each month. Example result would be

```
2015-01 1
2015-02 1
2015-03 1
2015-04 1
2015-05 2
2015-06 2
2015-07 2
2015-08 3
2015-09 3
...
2021-01 3
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with convert column to month periods and then [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by all possible periods by [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html), last add [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for cumulative sum:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('m')
p = pd.period_range(df['date'].min(), pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('m'), freq='m')

s = df.groupby('date').size().reindex(p, fill_value=0).cumsum()
print (s)
2015-01    1
2015-02    1
2015-03    1
2015-04    1
2015-05    2
          ..
2020-09    3
2020-10    3
2020-11    3
2020-12    3
2021-01    3
Freq: M, Length: 73, dtype: int64
```

Solution with datetimes with [`Series.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) and [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) :

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
s = df.resample('MS', on='date').size()

r = pd.date_range(s.index.min(), pd.to_datetime('today'), freq='MS')

s = s.reindex(r, fill_value=0).cumsum()
print (s)
2015-01-01    1
2015-02-01    1
2015-03-01    1
2015-04-01    1
2015-05-01    2
             ..
2020-09-01    3
2020-10-01    3
2020-11-01    3
2020-12-01    3
2021-01-01    3
Freq: MS, Length: 73, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This results in a list "how many items were purchased in each month". How do I apply cumulative sum to that, to achieve expected result?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев -  maximum value of `YYYY-MM` is today? Or max value of `date` column?

Comment: yes, it is today, so your current answer is almost correct.